# Designing a Persistence Layer

Tags: c#, architecture, persistence

For a project we are starting to look at persistence features and how we want to implement this. Currently we are looking at keeping Clean Architecture in mind, probably going for Onion Architecture. As such, we want to define a new outer layer which in which the persistence layer resides.

We're looking at various ORM solutions (we seem to be converging to Entity Framework) using SQLite as data store and we are hitting a snag: How should be manage ID's and deal with add/removal in some collection or move some instance between different collections.

In the core of our 'onion', we want to keep our POCO objects. As such, we do not want some kind of 'ID' property to be added in our business objects. Only inside the persistence layer do we want to have classes with object ID's. Because of this separation:

- how should removing a business object from some collection cause a row to be deleted from the SQLite database?
- More complex (at least I think it is), how should a POCO instance moved from 1 collection to another cause a foreign key of a SQLite databaserow to be changed? (Instead of removing the row and recreating it with the same values)

Looking around the internet I've yet to find an implementation somewhere that demonstrates a persistence layer in a Clean Architecture design. Plenty of high level diagrams and "depend only inward", but no source code examples to give a demonstration.
Some possible solutions that we came up with so far:

1. Have some lookup between POCO instances and their representative 'database model objects' (which have ID's etc) within the persistence layer. When saving the project state, business model objects will be matched with this database model objects and update the state for the matches accordingly. Then the object is persisted.
2. When loading a project, the persistence layer returns decorator objects of business objects that add an ID to the business object, which is only visible within the persistence layer by casting the objects to that decorator class. However, this prevents us from defining sealed POCO objects and seems to break the Clean Architecture design philosophy.

Option 1 seems costly in memory due to effectively doubling the business objects in memory. Option 2 seems the most elegant, but as I've written: it feels that it breaks Clean Architecture.

Are there better alternatives to there? Should we just go for Option 2 and take Clean Architecture more as guidelines than rule? Can someone point us to a working example in code (I did find a iOs example at https://github.com/luisobo/clean-architecture, but as I'm not literate in the language it cannot do much with it).

Comment: Actually, you're thinking about architectural issues too much. If your app is working with database, hiding `Id` is a kind of masochism. In other words: do not pretend, that there's no database, if there is one.

Comment: When you have to persist your POCOs individually -- whether that's to a database, flat file, web API or whatever -- you will need some way of uniquely identifying them. You can do this with a single ID property of some type (ie. an integer or a GUID), or with several properties that when combined together are unique. Presumably your persistence layer will have Insert/Update methods or maybe just Save methods; regardless, that layer must have some way of matching the POCOs to their corresponding persistence items. I don't see any way around that requirement.

Comment: @StevenRands: Option number two that we came up with, using a decorator for business objects, seems like an alternative to adding ID properties to POCO classes.

Comment: @Dennis: From the point of pragmatism, that might be the solution where we might en up eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, everything in the real world have ids. You have your social security number. Cars have their registration number. Items in shops have an EAN code (and a production identity). Without ids nothing in the world would work (a bit exaggerated, but hopefully you get my point).

*It's the same with applications.*

If your business objects do not have any natural keys (like a social security number) you MUST have a way to identify them. You application will otherwise fail as soon as you copy your object or transfer it over the process boundry. ***Because then it's a new object.*** It's like when you cloned the sheep Dolly. Is it the same sheep? No, it's Mini-Dolly.

The other part is that when you build complex structures you are violating the law of Demeter. For instance like:

```
public class ForumPost
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public User Creator { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

When you use that code and invoke:

```
post.User.FirstName = "Arnold"; 
postRepos.Update(post);
```

what do you expect to happen? Should your forum post repos suddenly be responsible of changes made in the user?

That's why ORMs are so sucky. They violate good architecture.

Back to ids. A good design is instead to use a ***user id***. Because then we do not break law of Demeter and still got a good separation of concern.

```
public class ForumPost
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public int CreatorId { get; set; }
}
```

So the conclusion is:

1. Do not abandon ids, as it introduces complexity when trying to identify the real object from all the copies of it that you *will* get.
2. Using ids when referencing different entities helps you keep a good design with distinct responsibilities.

Comment: Perhaps getting off-topic, but just by having a `User` reference on a `ForumPost` does not mean you are violating the law of Demeter. Accessing the exposed user such that you can modify its internal state while that shouldn't be the responsibility of the object aggregating that value is violating the law of Demeter. For example, retrieving the name of the user in the `ToString()` of `ForumPost` in order to create a textual representation feels perfectly fine, while being able to change the name wouldn't. Alternative: interface with readonly properties if Demeter's law becomes an issue.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned in the comments, IDs are a natural part of applications and are usually required in other parts than persistence. **So trying to avoid IDs at all costs is going to produce awkward designs.**

#### Identity Design

However, identity design (where to use which IDs, what information to put in IDs, user defined vs system generated, etc.) is something that is very important and requires thought.

**A good starting point to determine what requires an ID and what not is the Value Object / Entity distinction of domain-driven design.**

- Value objects are things that consist of other values and don't change - so you don't need an ID.
- Entities have a lifecycle and change over time. So their value alone is not enough to identify them - they  need an explicit ID.

As you see here, reasoning is very different from the technical point of view that you take in your question. This does not mean you should ignore constraints imposed by frameworks (e.g. entity framework), however.

If you want an in-depth discussion about identity design, I can recommend "Implementing DDD" by Vaughn Vernon (Section "Unique Identity" in Chapter 5 - Entities).

---

Note: I *don't* mean to recommend that you use DDD because of this. I just think that DDD has some nice guidelines about ID design. Whether or not to use DDD in this project is an entirely different question.